# How to read uint8_t data that was converted from vector of string?

Tags: c++, string, reinterpret-cast

I need to use a function `func(uint8_t* buffer, uint size)`; supposing I can't change its parameters, I want to pass it a string.

I have a `vector<string>` that I must convert to `uint8_t*` and then read it and convert it back to `vector<string>`.
I tried this code for reading (printing) the `vector.data()` output but it prints garbage:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>


int main() { 
    std::string a1 = {"ath"};
    std::cout <<"1: "<< a1<<" end\n";
    std::vector<std::string> vec;
    vec.push_back(a1);
    uint8_t *ptr = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(vec.data());
    std::cout <<"2: "<< ptr[0]<<" end\n";
}
```

output:

```
1: ath end
2: � end
```

questions:

1. why this doesn't work?
2. I saw in some links that they init a `std::string` with `char*` array like this:

```
char *ptr={'a'};
std::string myStr(ptr);
```

I suppose this works because of added '\0', is this related to my problem?

Comment: `vec.data()` will return a `std::string*` (because you have `std::string`s in your vector). Casting it to `uint8_t *` and using this pointer is UB (Undefined Behavior).

Comment: What did you expect it to print?

Comment: so how can I cast it back from uint8_t* to somthing I can print?

Comment: hm, converting `std::string*` to `uint8_t*` almost certainly does not yield what you hope to get. I think you're trying to solve a larger problem here (large string building, maybe?) that needs a completely different approach, but you forget to tell us what the actual thing you're trying to solve through all this is!

Comment: @AtheelMassalha you can't cast it "back to get something I can print", because there's no printable data in these `uint8_t`. That's the problem. You're mistaken about what `std::string` is. Please explain what you're actually trying to do, in the bigger picture.

Comment: @AtheelMassalha You must cast it back to the actual type, which is `std::string*`
.

Comment: "I have a vector<string> that I must convert to uint8_t*" This doesn't sound like a well-defined problem. Can you give an example? Say you have a vector that has three strings `{ "hola", " ", "mundo" }`. What do you want the conversion result to be?

Comment: If the purpose is serialization there is the issue that a `std::vector<std::string>` usually does **not** occupy a continuous block of memory. Each `std::string` usually keeps a pointer to a heap allocated memory (up to small string optimization). You'll need to serialize/deserialize each `std::string` separately.

Comment: I have a function that accepts : func(uint8_t* buffer, uint size)
supposing I can't change its parameters, I want to pass it a sting.
this function will print the buffer.

Comment: @wohlstad so I need to iterate over my vector, and insert each string to uint_8 buffer[vec.size()] ?

Comment: @AtheelMassalha no. `vec.size()` is the number of strings in your vector, not the sum of the length of the strings. You need to not use a vector of strings, but simply append the strings to each other, and then use the `c_str()` of the resulting string.

Comment: In addition to @MarcusMüller's comment, you might want to separate the strings in the resulting buffer with some special character, so that you can recover the separate strings at a later time.

Comment: @wohlstad don't think so, unless the target function `func` knows how to deal with these special characters.

Comment: @MarcusMüller sure. But I just mentioned it in case it does need to recover the separate strings. These details are not clear in the question.

Comment: @wohlstad There is a lot unclear in the question, but the OP does say that they need to recover the original vector.

Comment: @AtheelMassalha Impossible to answer because it's not clear what you mean by 'I want to convert ...'. You don't say and there's no obvious conversion that would work. I guess the reason you don't say is that you don't really know what you want. Can you think about that and then give an example of the conversion you want. Suppose the vector is `{ "aaa", "bbb" }` then what would you expect to be in the byte array? If you can answer that then it should be easy enough to write come code.

Comment: @john you are right. This means the solutions involving concatenation of the strings will not really work.

Answer (score 2):

> why this doesn't work?

This can't work, because a `std::string` is not just a contiguous piece of memory containing nothing but the characters in the string. You're simply mistaken about what `std::string` is!

Using a vector here is plain not the right approach. A vector does **not** contain your string's contents. Just the `std::string` objects themselves, which are not the string data.

Instead, you want to make one long `std::string`:

```cpp
std::string foo {"foo"};
std::string bar {"bar "};
std::string baz {"bazaz"};

std::string complete = foo + bar + baz;

auto* whole_cstring = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(complete.c_str());

// call your C-string-accepting function
func(whole_cstring, complete.length());
```

If you actually do have a `std::vector` of `std::string`s to begin with, the concatenation can be done in a simple loop:

```cpp
std::vector<std::string> my_vector_of_strings; 
// insert strings into the vector
/// … ///

std::string complete;
for(const auto& individual_string : my_vector_of_strings) {
  complete += individual_string;
}


auto* whole_cstring = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(complete.c_str());

// call your C-string-accepting function
func(whole_cstring, complete.length());
```

> … missing \0 … I suppose this works because of added '\0', is this related to my problem?

No, that's completely unrelated.

Comment: Note `reinterpret_cast` is a keyword, and you can't prefix it with `std::`

Comment: @Ranoiaetep oops. Happens every time. Thanks for pointing out!

Answer (score 0):

> I have a vector that I must convert to uint8_t*

```
std::vector<std::string> vec;
```

"Converting" has a relatively strong definition in the C++ (and other languages) world. If I understand what you *mean*, I'd suggest the following:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main(){
    std::vector<std::string> vec;
    // populate
    std::vector<uint8_t*> vec2(vec.size());
    std::transform(begin(vec), end(vec), begin(vec2), [](auto& s){ return reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(s.data()); });
}
```

Alternatively, if possible, you can use a `std::basic_string<uint8_t>` instead of `std::string` (a/k/a `std::basic_string<char>`) to avoid reinterpreting its content.